# Convert numpy slice to Opencv c++ Mat

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have an array in python with shape (1, 17, 17, 5, 5). I need to get a subarray of this array:

```
subarray = array[0]
subarray = subarray[:,:,:,4]
```

Now I need to write the same code in C++ using a Opencv Mat.
How do I get this subarray? Is there an easy way to slice a Mat same as with Numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using cv::Range to get the subarray I needed

```
std::vector<cv::Range> ranges;
ranges.push_back(cv::Range(0, 1));
ranges.push_back(cv::Range::all());
ranges.push_back(cv::Range::all());
ranges.push_back(cv::Range::all());
ranges.push_back(cv::Range(4, 5));

cv::Mat subarray = array(ranges);
```

It doesn't change the dimensions of the array, but makes sure I am only looking to the data that I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Opencv Matrices follow a completely different paradigm than numpy arrays, and thus you aren't going to be able to take advantage of broadcasting and other indexing features numpy allows.

Out side of special circumstances, OpenCV doesn't even support matrices over 3 dimensions due to how specialized OpenCV is towards computer vision.  If you *absolutely* need to use an opencv matrix for this, create a 1 dimensional opencv matrix of size `sum(array.shape)` and stuff all your data in in C order, then you can still use the general indexing formula for arbitrary dimensions:

```
cv::Mat your_mat = /*what ever data for your flattened matrix assuming double,*/
vector<int> dimensions = {/*what ever your dimensions are, in this case 1, 17, 17, 5, 5*/};
vector<int> nd_index = {/*what ever indexes you are trying to access, assuming x, y, z, ... order, not C order*/};
int accumulated_frame_size = 1;
int linear_index = 0;
for(int dim_idx = 0; dim_idx < dimensions.size(); ++dim_idx){
    linear_index += nd_index[dim_idx] * accumulated_frame_size;
    accumulated_frame_size *= nd_index[dim_idx];
}
//the value for that index. 
std::cout << your_mat.at<double>(linear_idx) << "\n";
```

Note of course most of what you probably want to do to operate on this probably won't work unless it is solely element wise.

Since you want to do something specific, we can do a bit better.  The first singleton dimension in our array wouldn't exist, since we flatten it in C++, so no need to subscript by `[0]`. If we think about it, `subarray[:,:,:,4]` is actually just the 4th index of every 5 element offset, nothing more.   To extract that information we first calculate how many of these elements we want to extract then input them in another matrix.

```
int extract_count =  17 * 17 * 5; //all dimensions before indexed dimension.
int final_dim_size = 5;
int extract_index = 4;
cv::Mat extracted_mat(1,extract_count,CV_64F);
for(int i = 0; i< extract_count ; ++i){
    extracted_mat.at<double>(i) = your_mat.at<double>(i*final_dim_size + extract_index);
}
```

What Numpy does is internally convert all indexes you make to similar operations.